# How do you build an HTML table with all rows and cells adjecent to each other?

Tags: html, css, doctype

Could someone help me resolve the discrepancies between the following two cases. In both cases I have split an image into several pieces and placed them in a table so that it still appears to be a single image.

However, in one case, I have set the doctype to  and in the other there is no doctype set. My expected result is shown when there is no doctype set ( no border-spacing or cellspacing or any other spaces between  the cells and the rows). However, when the doctype is set, there is a 1px padding in-between rows.

The HTML for both cases is the same except for the doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
    .table{
        display: table;
    }

    .row{
        display: table-row;
    }

    .cell{
        display: table-cell;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='slider' class='table'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_01.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_02.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_03.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_04.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_05.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_06.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_07.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_08.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_09.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_10.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_11.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_12.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_13.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_14.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_15.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_16.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_17.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
            <div class='cell'><img src='slides/1/1_18.gif' alt='slide' /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

could someone explain to me why there is a 1px gap between the rows when the doctype is set to HTML ?

Comment: have you tried `border-collapse: collapse;` ? Besides, what is the purpose of having a set of divs function like a table? why not just use `table`?

Comment: why don't you just use a table?

Comment: because i tend to strictly stick to the rule of not using tables except for tabular data in any circumstance. Here I am trying to create a layout for the images. although, using a table would have been easier.

Comment: I don't think using so many DIVs (in table mode, no less) would make much more sense, semantically. Depends on the use case I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Shafee: Try --

```
.row img {
    display: block;
}
```

**Edit**

Short explanation: your code with the `DOCTYPE` was triggering strict mode in your browser which handles the display of images differently.

Longer explanation:

> In the early days, experiments with
>   strict mode invariably raised the
>   comment that images suddenly got an
>   odd bottom margin that couldn’t be
>   removed. The cause was that in strict
>   mode `<img />` is an inline element,
>   which means that some space should be
>   reserved for possible descender
>   characters like g, j, or q. Of course
>   an image doesn’t have descender
>   characters, so the space was never
>   used, but it still had to be reserved.
>
> The solution was to explicitly declare
>   images block level elements: `img
>   {display: block}`.
>
> Nonetheless browser vendors, Mozilla
>   especially, thought this was such a
>   confusing situation that they
>   introduced "almost strict mode". This
>   was defined as strict mode, but with
>   images continuing to be blocks, and
>   not inline elements.
>
> Most common doctypes, including the
>   one I use, trigger almost strict mode.
>   The treatment of images is by far the
>   most important difference between
>   almost strict mode and really strict
>   mode.

Source: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: yeah. that works. thanks :D.. but can you please explain why it did?

Answer (score 0):

Remove whitespace around your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Charles Upsdell's [site](http://www.upsdell.com/BrowserNews/res_doctype.htm) has more info on how `DOCTYPE` affects rendering generally.